# How to show documents that users are following in SharePoint 2019

Tags: document, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am working with SP2019. Microsoft deprecated newsfeed in SP2019, so from a classic site collection perspective, what is the option to show documents that users are following either from a user or admin perspective.

If someone knows an answer, please shed some light, thanks in advance.